# Problem with Express in NodeJS: Express doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have this code:

```
app.get("/v1/send", async (req, res) => {
    if(isNaN(parseInt(req.query.keys))) {
        process.stdout.write(req.query.keys);
        cmdOutput += req.query.keys;
        cmd.stdin.write(req.query.keys);
    }else {
        process.stdout.write(String.fromCharCode(req.query.keys));
        cmdOutput += String.fromCharCode(req.query.keys);
        cmd.stdin.write(String.fromCharCode(req.query.keys));
    }
    res.status(200).send();
    finishRequest(req, "success");
});
```

but code not working. tell me what wrong and how fix thanks a lot. also, please salute to me because i am jsmasder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if `finishRequest(req, "success")` works once server response back to the client.
You could shuffle position of the last two function.

Comment: hello, i am very thankful for your answer.